# Multi join select query on Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

How to write this query in Laravel. I am new in laravel.

Example:

```
    SELECT * FROM ((respassanger join ((`reservation` join flightres 
    on flightres.res_id = reservation.id)) on respassanger.res_id = reservation.id) 
    join passanger on respassanger.pas_id = passanger.pas_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation? Checkout Laravel's [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries). Using your table names as mentioned, work from the following example in the docs for your needs:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')->orOn(...);
    })
    ->get();
```

So something like:

```
DB::table('respassanger')
    ->join('reservation', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('flightres.res_id', '=', 'reservation.id') 
    })
    ->join('passanger', 'respassanger.pas_id', '=', 'passanger.pas_id')
    ->select( ... )
    ->get();
```

Not sure how correct the above is, but tweak it if it doesn't work.